# How to get the array value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, I am getting array values as "488,489" I need to get each value from the array into the variable `chkval`. How can I get them using jQuery?

```
var ALLArr = optionIds ? optionIds.split(",") : '';  //here i will get all values
var selectedArry = selectedValue ? selectedValue.split(',') : '';  //here only checked values
    $.each(ALLArr , function (k, v) {
    //from those checked values i need to get each value
    }
```

Comment: [This works, what's the problem?](https://jsbin.com/xepunofija/edit?js,console)

Comment: Wait, I posted the comment before I saw the edit. I'm now more confused what the problem is. What is `CidArr` and how is it relevant?

Comment: Only problem in this code is that when trying to read a value from `ValArry` index is capital instead of lowercase

Comment: sorry its not cidarr its Valarry

Comment: @StefanPopovski you have turned `i` into capital `I` while editing ;) I've fixed it

Comment: which i you have changed to I

Comment: Why do you absolutely want jQuery simply to iterate an array? There's no need for it at all

Comment: ya i need to get only the selectedArry values

Answer (score 0):

Just use this for any array

```
var myArray = [ 52, 97 ];
$.each(myArray , function( index, value ) {
    alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```